# Python - alternating lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists in python:

```
l = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
b = ['-', 2, 2, 2, '-', 2]
```

In the end, I'd like to have a list like this:

result = [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]

Algorithm:
    If there is a '-' in b, do nothing, else append element from b after element in l at same    index (Second 2 from b should go after second 1 in l). How can I do this?

```
    for idx, i2 in enumerate(b):
    if i2 != '-' and count == 1:
        l.insert(prev+2,i2)
        prev = prev+2
        print "in if1"
        print l
        print prev
    elif i2 != '-' and count == 0:
        l.insert(idx+1,i2)
        prev = idx+2
        count = 1
        print "in if2"
        print l
        print prev
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l, b = [1,1,1,1,1,1], ['-', 2, 2, 2, '-', 2]
print [item for items in zip(l, b) for item in items if item != '-']
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

If the number of elements in either of the lists is not going to be equal to the other, you can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) like this

```
l, b = [1,1,1,1,1,1], ['-', 2, 2, 2, '-', 2, 2, 2]
from itertools import izip_longest
print [e for items in izip_longest(l,b) for e in items if e != None and e != '-']
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used "chained" list comprehenstion (i.e. with two `for` loops), and a filter (`x!='-'`):

```
l1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
l2 = ['-', 2, 2, 2, '-', 2]

[ x for (a,b) in zip(l1,l2) for x in (a,b) if x != '-' ]
=> [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```